# Current hour nearest to half an hour with next hour time

Tags: javascript

I have two textbox with value to set start time and end time. If user has selected these times then it will be display those value. But, if user is creating a new appointment then by default it should display nearest half an hour time to current one and end time should be next hour duration.

For example,

The current time is 4:37PM then the start time should be 5:00PM and end time should be 6:00PM
If the current time is 7:31AM then the start time should be 8:00AM and end time should be 9:00AM.
If the current time is 11:45AM then the start time should be 12:00PM and end time should 01:00PM

Comment: Divide the minutes with 60 and do [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) on the result, getting either 0 or 1 back?

Comment: use a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and `date.setMinutes(Math.ceil(date.getMinutes() / 30) * 30, 0, 0)`

Comment: None of your examples show an option where rounding-*down* would be in effect - eg what happens at 4:05pm?   Otherwise just create a date with hours+1 and 0 minutes.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the example a bit, so that when the user sets in 8:00 it stays at 8:00, anything else goes to the next 30 minutes (which you could easily change)

A downside of this approach is that setting 8:30 makes it 9:00 as well, whereas you could possibly argue that 8:30 is valid as well, as it is at 30 minutes intervals

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const startElement = document.querySelector('#startTime');
  const endElement = document.querySelector('#endTime');
  const detailsElement = document.querySelector('#appointment_details');
  
  function createTimeString( hours, minutes ) {
    if (hours < 0 || minutes < 0) {
      throw 'argument exception';
    }
    console.log( 'original input ' + hours + ':' + minutes );
    while (parseInt(hours) >= 24) hours = +hours - 24;
    while (parseInt(minutes) >= 60) {
      minutes = +minutes - 60;
      hours = +hours + 1;
    }
    return hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  }

  function handleStartTimeChanged( e ) {
    const timeValue = e.target.value;
    let [hours,minutes] = timeValue.split(':');
    if (Math.round( parseInt( minutes ) / 60.0) === 1) {
      hours = parseInt(hours) + 1;
      minutes = 0;
    } else if (parseInt( minutes ) !== 0) {
      // anything else is same hour but 30 minutes past
      minutes = 30;
    }
    setAppointmentDetails( createTimeString( hours, minutes ), createTimeString( +hours + 1, minutes ) );
  }

  function handleEndTimeChanged( e ) {
    const timeValue = e.target.value;
    let [hours,minutes] = timeValue.split(':');
    if (Math.round( parseInt( minutes ) / 60.0) === 1) {
      hours = parseInt(hours) + 1;
      minutes = 0;
    } else if (parseInt( minutes ) !== 0) {
      // anything else is same hour but 30 minutes past
      minutes = 30;
    }
    setAppointmentDetails( createTimeString( hours - 1, minutes ), createTimeString( hours, minutes ) );
  }
  
  function setAppointmentDetails( startTime, endTime ) {
    detailsElement.innerHTML = `${startTime} till ${endTime}`;
  }

  startElement.addEventListener('change', handleStartTimeChanged );
  endElement.addEventListener('change', handleEndTimeChanged );

} );
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <span class="label">Appointment start:</span>
  <span class="field"><input type="time" id="startTime" /></span>
  <span class="label">Appointment end:</span>
  <span class="field"><input type="time" id="endTime" /></span>
</div>
<div id="appointment_details">
</div>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m true, well, I did a little change for that

Answer (score 0):

This involves some fairly simple calculations, and `Math.ceil`:

```js
const secsPerHalfHour = 1000 * 60 * 30

const nextHalfHour = () => 
  new Date (Math .ceil (new Date() .getTime() / secsPerHalfHour) * secsPerHalfHour)

const next90Mins = () => 
  new Date (Math .ceil ((new Date() .getTime() / secsPerHalfHour) + 2) * secsPerHalfHour)


console .log (`start: ${nextHalfHour()}`)
console .log (`end: ${next90Mins()}`)
```